# Constantly changing data and caching?

Tags: c#, caching, architecture, distributed-system, distributed-caching

Currently I have one server with a C# net core console app that takes incoming TCP IOT data.
Each device reports every 5 seconds and there are 30,000 devices

I now need to move to distributed model where HAProxy distributes data using leastconn model (long running TCP connections) to multiple servers
The issue I have is each new bit of information from the IOT device is compared against its "last record" and logic fires if there is a state change etc

As the IOT devices have sim cards, I have seen TCP connections get interrupted and the next time it connects it gets routed to different server and its "last record" is very old and not the actual last record
This causes obvious data consistency issues.
I can live with the "last record"  being a 1 min out of data, but not much more

I had started to look into caching with redis and memcached, but from what I read, you should use caching for infrequently changing data, whereas mine is changing every 5 secs

As I can I see I have the following options

1. configure haproxy to sticky sessions from IP address to certain server - not perfect and will imbalance loads as each IOT device can report on same IP/different port.
2. Use local in mem cache and distributed cache, then broadcast recent data every 1 min to the main cache, and pull from main cache every 1 min on all servers

Is there something else i'm not considering?

What software engineering patterns exist to solve this problem?
And is a cache not suitable for this scenario ?

Comment: Although this is a good question, it's a fairly broad topic and these are frowned upon in here unfortunately... You may want to widen your spectrum of ideas by 
 searching for 'cache frequently changing data'.

Comment: thanks, i've already spent a few weeks looking into this and researching online, and I cannot find anything relevant, what I can see is people saying cache infrequently changed but highly queried data, this is mainly a software architecture pattern question, and i assumed there must be some patterns that apply to this use case, and perhaps my suggestions are an anti-pattern. One suggestion I saw was to cache locally and on caching server and broadcast the changes on a schedule (but not each update as it will smash the caching server and wont scale well)

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't restrict myself into asking only at SO, see wherever else you can ask about, HAProxy seems to have a discussion thread for instance.

Comment: this looks relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/caching#cache-highly-dynamic-data

Comment: From what i've read, it seems I need a central Redis cache, and an in memory cache, then I should be getting and setting back and forth on a schedule, although it does sound like a lot of custom work, i would hope something already exists to achieve this